# C++ overloading >> operator strange compile error

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class phonebook
{
    string name;
    string prefix;
public:
    phonebook(string &name, string &prefix)
    {
        this->name = name;
        this->prefix = prefix;
    }

    friend istream &operator>>(istream &in, phonebook &book);
};

istream &phonebook::operator>>(istream &in, phonebook &book)
{
    in >> book.name >> book.prefix;
    return in;
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile this code using g++ 4.6.1:

"main.cpp:20: error: ‘std::istream& phonebook::operator>>(std::istream&, phonebook&)’ must take exactly one argument"

PS: It was pretty dumb thing to ask... So obvious :S. Thank you though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot overload `operator >>` for streaming as a member function. Any operator that is defined as a member function takes its first argument as a reference to (const) Type, where Type is your class name - in this case, phonebook.

You need to change

```
istream &phonebook::operator>>(istream &in, phonebook &book)
```

to

```
istream & operator>>(istream &in, phonebook &book)
```

Answer (score 3):

A `friend` function isn't a member. As it is, it's expecting the left-hand side of the `>>` operator to be a `phonebook`. Change the first line of the function definition (outside the class) to this:

```
istream &operator>>(istream &in, phonebook &book)
```

Note there is no `phonebook::` because it's not a member.

Answer (score 1):

`phonebook` doesn't have a method called `opeartor>>`

You stated that there exists a **global** function that is a friend of `phonebook`, and therefore, you should remove `phonebook::` from the implementation of `operator>>`

Answer (score 1):

because you declared `friend istream &operator>>(istream &in, phonebook &book);`

So this operator>> is not a member function of phonebook.

**Quote from C++ 03 standard**

11.4 Friends
A friend of a class is a function or class that is **not** a member of the class but is permitted to use the private and protected member names from the class. The name of a friend is not in the scope of the class, and the friend is not called with the member access operators (5.2.5) unless it is a member of another class.

So remove the `phonebook::` would work:

```
istream& operator>>(istream &in, phonebook &book)
{
    in >> book.name >> book.prefix;
    return in;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare function a friend inside the class, you either define it inside the class or make it a non-member function.

```
istream & operator>>(istream &in, phonebook &book)
{
    in >> book.name >> book.prefix;
    return in;
}
```